# Automatic touch on android device(sending touch impulses)

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I want to know if it is possible to generate automatic touch at regular intervals of time, say 5 seconds in another application.
For example..I want to develop an application which will create a touch response just as we touch the screen, at a particular coordinate at regular fixed interval.
Please help.

Comment: Do you need for testing?

Comment: No. i want to develop a application as mentioned above...all i want to know that is it possible on android..does android have any features for developing such app

Comment: Do you have a touchscreen in your monitor, In my cause it was causing issue. I touched the screen and it got fixed. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create and dispatch touch events in your application. It's pretty easy. Look at View.dispatchTouchEvent method and parameters. You have to override that method in root view group so you can pass your events to all views in the activity.

It's not possible to access other applications though (due to security reasons).

edit: seems like dispatchTouchEvent is public, so no need to override

Comment: windows 7(desktop) have auto clicker kind of application which works over all other application and generates automatic click in all windows apps...is there no possibility in android in the same way?

Comment: No. Android runs applications in safe sandboxes which prevents cross application access. Android is meant to be safe for users without good understanding of permissions, profiles, device capabilities and system administration. That's why it prohibits potentially dangerous actions.